# Dynamically fill the predefined Relative layout

Tags: android, xml

so i have an relative layout which looks like this..

[Click for screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0khRU.jpg)

and it's code is:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/image"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="#60000000"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textAlignment="textEnd"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

I've got two things to do firstly use this relative layout again and again dynamically and fill the imageview and textview with different content.

Secondly I want to arrange the Relativelayout dynamically one after another
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJCjG.jpg).

Comment: use `RecyclerView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use RecyclerView for that

you Can learn them from

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html

and

http://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/

Comment: thanks a lot... btw how to arrange them one after another dynamically...!! :)

Comment: you have to set Layout Manager as Linear Layout Manger for that recycler view , please refer to the documentation and tutorials of recyclerview  the Linear One after another is got by  recyclerView.setLayoutManger(new LinearLayoutManager(context));

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is using `RecyclerView`for this kind of need. But still you should achieve this by **inflating** and adding this layout to parent layout.

Imagine you have a model that contains background and text

```
public class Item {
    private String text;
    private int background;

    public Item (String text_, int background_) {
        this.text = text_;
        this.background = background_;
    }

    public String getText() { return this.text; }

    public int getBackground() { return this.background; }
}
```

Let's say you have an `ArrayList<Item>` of this object. And you have a parent linear layout.

```
LinearLayout parentLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.parent_layout);
for (Item item: items) {
        View view = getLayoutInflater(null).inflate(R.layout.your_button_layout,  parentLayout, false);
        TextView text= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text);
        ImageView background= (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
        text.setText(item.getText());
        background.setBackground(item.getBackground());

        parentLayout.addView(view);
    }
```

You can apply margin & padding attributes to your child layout to have similar look like `RecyclerView`